# how to run all (unit and instrumented) tests with one click in Android Studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio

I am developing an Android app in Android Studio.
I have unit tests and instrumented tests.

I want to run them all to see if I broke something.

Right now my workflow is:

- go to Project view

  - navigate to `${app}/src/androidTest/java/`
  - right-click that node and select `Run 'All Tests'`
  - select my device
  - run instrumented tests

then

- go to Project view

  - navigate to `${app}/src/androidTest/java/${package}`
  - right-click that node and select `Run 'Tests in ${package}'`
  - run unit tests

What I am really looking for is a big green button that runs all of the tests and reports back the result of OK/FAILED for both unit and instrumented tests together. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7):

You cannot start both tests at the same time...

But you can create two big green buttons.

1. Go to your project files and right click on `../app/src/androidTest/java`
   [image: make all instrumented tests]
2. Then right click on `../app/src/test/java`
   [image: make all unit tests]
3. Enjoy! =)

[image: like this]

Comment: The above answer works if you only have one module. If you have multiple modules and want to run all of your tests for all modules in that project, check out my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56192783/2441420

Comment: this sucks. The root principle of TDD editing is you run _all_ tests with _one_ button. Not "different tests because..."

Answer (score 1):

Use this way for all modules in a project.

**1.Select Edit Configurations from Android Stduio**

[image]

**2.Add Gradle task**

[image]

**3. Set this config**

cleanTestDebugUnitTest testDebugUnitTest

--tests "*"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to make 1 button that runs both all unit tests and instrumentation/UI tests:

### Steps

1. Create a Run Configuration > `Gradle` > Named: `Unit Tests`
2. Create a Run Configuration > `Android Instrumentation Tests` > Named `Unit + UI Tests`
3. For the `Unit + UI Tests` configuration > `Before Launch` Option > Add `Run Another Configuration` > `Unit Tests`
4. Run your new `Unit + UI Tests` configuration. Your Unit tests and UI Tests will both run but they will be in separate tabs, since each tab has specific tooling options.

### Same Steps as Above but with pictures:

##### 1. Create a Run Configuration > `Gradle` > Named: `Unit Tests`

[image]

[image]

[image]

##### 2. Create a Run Configuration > `Android Instrumentation Tests` > Named `Unit + UI Tests`

[image]

##### 3. For the `Unit + UI Tests` configuration > `Before Launch` Option > Add `Run Another Configuration` > Select the newly created `Unit Tests` configuration

[image]

[image]

##### 4. Run your new `Unit + UI Tests`. Your Unit tests and UI Tests will both run but they will be in separate tabs, since each tab has specific tooling options.

[image]

Comment: Is this multi module or single module as see you select a module for instrumented test but i have like 20 modules in project