# Run all unit tests in Android Studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, android-instrumentation

I have this project in Android Studio :

[image]

I wish to run all unit tests in all project with one click.

How i can do it ?

Comment: All of the answers up unto this point have provided an option, but do not utilize the Android Studio test runner (that allows you to jump to source, quickly view results of tests, etc). In order to use those features, you simply need to create a new run configuration that targets the entire project's tests. I have detailed these steps in my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56192783/2441420

Comment: you can see the post https://stackoverflow.com/a/71138713/4797289

Answer (score 59, accepted):

First, you can list all the test tasks available in your project with

```
./gradlew tasks
```

Then you can choose the tasks you want to execute. If you want to execute all tests for all flavors ans all buildTypes, you just have to run

```
./gradlew test connectedAndroidTest
```

If you don't want to remember all the gradle test command each time you want to run the tests, you can create a file "custom_tasks.gradle" and add

```
task testAll(dependsOn: ['test', 'connectedAndroidTest']) {
   group = 'custom_tasks'
   description = "Run all tests"
}
```

Then, you just have to run

```
./gradlew testAll
```

Comment: I just added the task to my app's gradle file and changed the group line to `group = 'Verification'`, thanks for the advice!

Comment: But question is about android studio, he specifically mention one click also so its quite obvious and I am here also because of it. But this answer to run by gradle from command line.. better answer would be, no it's not possible using android studio test runner.

Comment: @Renetik the `testAll` task will appear in the Gradle dialog in Android Studio where you can 'double' click it to run it! Two clicks, I know, but we can let that one slide can't we?

Comment: @Renetik running tests with the Android Studio test runner is possible. In short, you have to create a run configuration that targets all of the Project's tests. Please see my answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56192783/2441420

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line

Answer (score 80):

Not sure what version of Android Studio this was added in, but I'm using **Android Studio 3.4**.

[image: Android Studio Version 3.4]

In the Project Explorer Window, select the *Project View*.

[image: Project View Select]

Right click on your root project and select "Create 'All Tests'..."

[image: Create 'All Tests']

...*this window will appear (these defaults need to be changed)*

[image: Default edit config window]

Change the following options:

- Search for tests:

  - **In whole project**
- JRE:

  - Most recent version of Android API __ Platform that you have available in this menu (for me, **Android API 28 Platform**
- **Click Apply**

[image: Edited Test configuration]

- Select "All Tests" from the drop down menu

[image]

- View output from all your tests

[image]

Comment: Finally - this is literally the most common thing you should do before checking in code! In case it's not clear, it can also be done through the "Edit Configurations..." option from the Run/Debug drop-down combo. I didn't have to change the JRE from Default. I wish there was something similar for Android Instrumented Tests, but they must be created on a per-module basis as they don't seem to support searching the whole project for tests.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to run Unit Test via command line (for my CI server), it always works with Android Studio, but won't work with command line as it always gives a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException error. After a while, I learned that there's something different. When I run the test from AS, it says Executing tasks: [:lib_view:generateDebugSources, ...] it seems that ./gradlew test skip generateDebugSources task so it can't find the class, do you know what command does AS run when we click run test?

Comment: This only seems to work for unit tests. What about androidTests?

Comment: This really should be built in as a default configuration.  

Comment: That's a surprising amount of steps!

Answer (score 39):

With AndroidStudio ArcticFox the approach is as follows:

In the toolbar under the run configuration select "Edit Configurations"
[image: Menu entry]

Select (+) to add a new configuration and choose Gradle:

[image: Add configuration]

On the configuration page:

- give the configuration a **Name** (Run all unit tests)
- Choose your root project as **Gradle Project**
- add the **Tasks** `cleanTestDebugUnitTest testDebugUnitTest` (you can copy that from an existing configuration for unit tests, but make sure to remove the module prefix (e.g. :app:))
- [Seems like this step is no longer required in latest AS version] add `--tests "*"` as **Arguments** (apparently that tells AS to show the results as TestResults)

[image: configuration]

Select and run your new configuration. The Results will be shown in the run window:
[image: Test run results]

Comment: What's `cleanTestDebugUnitTest` for?

Comment: @mikeD cleanTestDebugUnitTest is for cleaning the build first, as far as I know. It is usually added by AS on every Unit test configuration you run manually. (I often remove it to save some time)

Answer (score 22):

1. In "Project" panel (CMD+1 to show) Right click on "java".
2. Click "Run tests in Java

Comment: this ignores some tests as well

Comment: this only runs tests in that directory. OP is asking for all test directories in the project

Comment: This is no longer available

Comment: This works for me as of AS 3.3.2, 2 clicks to run all my tests, one on androidTest/java and another on src/test/java

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky It is as of Android Studio 3.4. The trick is to create another run configuration for all of your tests within the project. See my answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56192783/2441420

Answer (score 12):

You can try to use this command line on the android terminal: 
Mac:

```
./gradlew test connectedAndroidTest
```

Windows:

```
gradlew test connectedAndroidTest
```

Answer (score 2):

In terminal: ./gradlew testDebugUnitTest

Answer (score 1):

Open Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1

1. Open Gradle panel on the right-top side
2. Project name -> Tasks -> verification -> click "test***Debug***UnitTest" (***Debug*** is your variants)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you're having issues running the command from cmd. You can run the command in android studio

1. Click on Gradle on the right side of Android Studio.
2. Click on "Execute Gradle Task" icon
3. Type command "gradle test connectedAndroidTest" and enter