# Android Studio doesn't run all Unit Tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, junit

Trying to run all unit tests and receive this error:

[image]

Comment: Without seeing your project, (and specifically whether or not you have configured your tests properly) it is hard to determine what the issue is. However, I have just written up an answer on how to run all of your tests within Android Studio's test runner. Let me know if that helps you! https://stackoverflow.com/a/56192783/2441420